# Admobadapter customize ad layout

Tags: android, admob, adapter

https://github.com/clockbyte/admobadapter

I am using Admobadapter library.  It's perfectly. But how can I customize native ad layout? [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use native express ads. More info on Firebase [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/native-express).

There you can customize the ads with CSS or choose from some different templates.

You will need to change your adapter from using `AdmobAdapterWrapper` to instead use `AdmobExpressAdapterWrapper` or to `AdmobExpressRecyclerAdapterWrapper` depending on whether you are using recyclerview or listview.